# How to unit test videojs record feature with Karma-Jasmine in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, video.js

I'm trying to unit test start record in Video.js.
I have created a mock player object for video.js.
When I unit test it, it breaks.

Code

```js
      authBtn() { 
        if(this.deviceId ==''){
          this.helper.toastErrorMessage('Please Select Camera');
          return;
        }
        playerStatus = true;
        player.record().start();
      }
// Unit Test Code
      describe('AuthenticateCandidateComponent', () => {
      it('should display error message and return if deviceId is empty', () => {
        spyOn(component.helper, 'toastErrorMessage');
        component.deviceId = ''; 
        component.playerStatus=true;
        component.authBtn(); expect(component.helper.toastErrorMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Please Select Camera');
        expect(component.playerStatus).toBeTrue();
      });
    
      it('should start recording when authBtn is called', () => {
        component.player = {
          record: jasmine.createSpyObj('record', ['start']), 
        };
        component.authBtn();
        expect(component.playerStatus).toBe(true);
        expect(component.player.record().start).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Unit Test breaks here 
      });
      
      });
```

Error & Stack trace

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'record')
    at AuthenticateCandidateComponent.selectedData in authenticate-candidate.component.ts
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (authenticate-candidate/authenticate-candidate.component.spec.ts:369:15)
```